# A problem in vectors with a pyramid whose base is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors

In the drawing, $ABCDS$ is a pyramid whose base is a parallelogram. $O$ is the intersection of the parallelogram diagonals. The following holds:

- $\overrightarrow{SF} = k \cdot \overrightarrow{SD}$
- $\overrightarrow{SE} = t \cdot \overrightarrow{SO}$

The problem is to express $t$ using $k$.

[image]

Comment: What are $E$ and $F$? Is $SO$ perpendicular to the base? Are the lengths of the edges known?

Comment: $E$ and $F$ are points. It's unkown whether $SO$ is perpendicular to the base, as well as what the lengths of the edges are.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Draw $M$ on $SD$ such that $EM\parallel BD$. Then you have $SM=t\cdot SD$ and $FM=(t/2)FD$. From $SM=SF+FM$ you can then find $t=2k/(k+1)$.

Comment: Why is $FM=(t/2)FD$?

Comment: $FM/FD=EM/BD$, but $EM=t\cdot OD$ and $BD=2OD$.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanx! Meanwhile I've found in the internet another solution, which involves writing $\overrightarrow{BF}=c\overrightarrow{EF}$ for some real number $c$.